# New Vimeo API, no ID's being passed back for videos and groups?

Tags: vimeo-api

What's happened to the ID fields for groups and videos? The Simple API does give you ID's but the new API isn't, though you do get a URL field with what looks like an ID in it.

Seems you only get a url field now? Can that be used as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In the v3 API, the IDs have been removed and instead the unique thing for each item is the URI.  You should be able to use the whole URI to uniquely identify the items, but the ID shouldn't need to be extracted from them and presents a list of potential pitfalls since that's an unsupported use case.

Depending on your use case, there are different approaches that make sense for this:

1. If it's for managing your local cache, you can use the URI safely to uniquely identify the response.
2. If it's for forming subsequent requests, you will likely find them already formed for you in the `metadata` key for the response (inside either `connections` or `interactions`).

For finding the URI from a Vimeo video, we now include the URI inside the oEmbed response.

Comment: Thankyou very much for this full and clear reply, makes perfect sense.